# How do you grab a key/value pair from an array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes (or atleast I think they are hashes) and I need to pull out the ID for each of them. I'm sure ruby has some quick way of doing this ... I just can't figure it out.

I don't want to iterate through the arrays and build a new one.

```
[
  [
    {
      "bio": "I am a tech geek who loves starting up companies. While I was in college, I founded Squeeze My Tees",
      "business_name": "Rounded Development",
      "city": "",
      "created_at": "2012-04-22T18:07:44Z",
      "first_name": "Brian",
      "id": 1,
      "industry": "Entertainment",
      "last_name": "Weinreich",
      "lat": null
    },
    {
      "access_token": null,
      "bio": null,
      "business_name": null,
      "city": null,
      "created_at": "2012-04-23T13:56:35Z",
      "email": "test@jambo.com",
      "first_name": "asdad",
      "id": 2,
      "industry": null,
      "last_name": "ddfs",
      "lat": null,
      "linkedin_id": null,
      "linkedin_url": null,
      "lng": null,
      "position": null,
      "professional_headline": null,
      "state": null,
      "street": null,
      "updated_at": "2012-04-23T13:56:35Z"
    },
    {
      "access_token": null,
      "bio": null,
      "business_name": null,
      "city": null,
      "created_at": "2012-04-23T13:56:39Z",
      "email": "tesasdat@jambo.com",
      "first_name": "fdsd",
      "id": 3,
      "industry": null,
      "last_name": "asdgw",
      "lat": null,
      "linkedin_id": null,
      "linkedin_url": null,
      "lng": null,
      "position": null,
      "professional_headline": null,
      "state": null,
      "street": null,
      "updated_at": "2012-04-23T13:56:39Z"
    },
    {
      "access_token": null,
      "bio": null,
      "business_name": null,
      "city": null,
      "created_at": "2012-04-23T13:56:44Z",
      "email": "asdsad@jambo.com",
      "first_name": "ewtrwef",
      "id": 4,
      "industry": null,
      "last_name": "dfd",
      "lat": null,
      "linkedin_id": null,
      "linkedin_url": null,
      "lng": null,
      "position": null,
      "professional_headline": null,
      "state": null,
      "street": null,
      "updated_at": "2012-04-23T13:56:44Z"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: You need to fix your hashes: it's '=>', not ':' and 'nil' instead of 'null', i.e. it should look like this: `"lat" => nil`. Also you have one too many levels of arrays in the example. Unless you're actually use array of arrays of hashes.

Comment: @TsukinoMai I think the OP actually posted JSON, and not Ruby. Otherwise yes, you'd be correct in how the hash should use `=>` instead of `:`.

Comment: @MrDanA Well, he'll need to make it into a ruby hash if he wants to use ruby methods to grab info. In current state your solution (or any other for that matter) will just shower him with errors.

Comment: Sorry, I did post the result of the .json page, but it ended up working in my model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull out just the IDs you can do this:

```
the_IDs = array_of_hashes.collect { |single_array| single_array["id"] }
```

Obviously you can use less verbose variable names, they're just for illustration. But the idea is that you can loop through an array and collect whatever the block returns. In this case, you keep getting an ID returned, and `the_IDs` will just be an array of what was collected.